# laravel Auth::logoutOtherDevices() doesn't redirect to login page?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, authentication, laravel-5

i am using Auth::logoutOtherDevice() in laravel and it logs out user from other sessions  but they need to refresh to get to login page . why Doesn't it redirect automatically to login page?

If not than , how do i redirect all devices automatically?

Comment: `logoutOtherDevices()` invalidates Sessions, how would you expect it to redirect each end-user to a login screen? Sessions are stored in a variety of ways; file, database, cookies, etc.; invalidating that is not a front-end interaction. The idea is that when the end user goes to interact with the web page, _then_ they will be redirected and have to sign in again.

Comment: @TimLewis So i have to use middleware and make it check all routes , so when it gets unauthenticated user it will redirect to login page ? Isn't there some two line way ? hehe~

Comment: You don't _have_ to do anything. When the end user goes to interact with the webpage on their device **after** `logoutOtherDevices()` is called, they will simply see that they have been logged out. Whether or not your website forces them to be redirected to the login screen is dependent on what page they were on before. If that Route associated with that page requires them to be logged in, they will have to login again. If it was not, they won't have to. But, it would be non-trivial (i.e. very difficult, but not impossible) to trigger a redirect on **their device** from that call.

Comment: @TimLewis No they don't get redirected directly ...but they have to refresh since nothing works, which lead them to login page then

Comment: but my senior wants to spoon feed users ...he say you gotta rediect them somehow without them refreshing

Comment: That's a pretty silly requirement when Laravel's middleware will already handle that when the User goes to interact with your webpage... But I get it. There are ways to broadcast events from backend code in Laravel, and listen to those events on the front-end via JS, which in-turn could trigger a redirect, but again, that is not trivial. Or you could look into something called a "heartbeat" function, which is periodic "ping" from your front-end to your backend to see if your session is still valid, and display a Model (or trigger a redirect) if it is not.